# During Deploy build in aws use cicden facing the issue

Tags: amazon-web-services

1. @angular/cli@16.2.0 added 248 packages from 165 contributors in 27.676s  [Container] 2023/08/24 11:07:23 Running command npm install npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL npm ERR! Could not install from "node_modules/jspdf/file-saver@github:eligrey/filesaver.js#1.3.8" as it does not contain a package.json file.

package json file

```
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.1.0",
    "@angular/animations": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/fire": "^5.4.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "^8.2.14",
    "@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet": "^6.0.1",
    "@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet-markercluster": "^5.0.1",
    "@ctrl/ngx-emoji-mart": "^0.17.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.12.0",
    "@fullcalendar/angular": "^5.10.1",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^5.10.1",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^5.10.1",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^5.10.1",
    "@fullcalendar/list": "^5.10.1",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^5.10.1",
    "@microsoft/signalr": "^5.0.2",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^5.1.5",
    "@ng-plus/signature-pad": "0.0.5",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^3.7.3",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^8.6.0",
    "@ngrx/entity": "^8.6.0",
    "@ngrx/router-store": "^8.6.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^8.6.0",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^8.6.0",
    "@ngx-loading-bar/core": "^4.2.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.15.0",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.39.4",
    "@types/leaflet.markercluster": "^1.4.5",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.149",
    "ack-angular-webcam": "^1.10.0",
    "amplitude-js": "^8.5.0",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "^0.8.0",
    "angular-split": "^4.0.0",
    "apexcharts": "^3.29.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
    "chartist": "^0.11.4",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.5",
    "core-js": "^3.6.2",
    "exceljs": "^4.0.0",
    "express-static-gzip": "^2.0.7",
    "fastdom": "^1.0.10",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "firebase": "^6.1.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "highlight.js": "^9.17.1",
    "interactjs": "^1.8.3",
    "jspdf": "^1.5.3",
    "jspdf-autotable": "^3.5.28",
    "leaflet": "^1.7.1",
    "leaflet.markercluster": "^1.5.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "logrocket": "^1.0.7",
    "lottie-web": "^5.7.13",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "moment-range": "^4.0.2",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.31",
    "mydaterangepicker": "^4.2.1",
    "ng-apexcharts": "^1.5.6",
    "ng-image-fullscreen-view": "^1.0.3",
    "ng-inline-svg": "^9.2.2",
    "ng2-daterangepicker": "^2.0.12",
    "ngrx-store-freeze": "^0.2.4",
    "ngrx-store-localstorage": "^8.0.0",
    "ngx-clipboard": "^12.3.0",
    "ngx-color-picker": "^8.1.0",
    "ngx-dropzone": "^2.3.0",
    "ngx-highlightjs": "^3.0.3",
    "ngx-image-cropper": "^3.3.1",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^9.0.0",
    "ngx-joyride": "^2.4.0",
    "ngx-lottie": "^7.0.3",
    "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^8.0.0",
    "ngx-permissions": "^7.0.3",
    "ngx-print": "^1.2.1",
    "ngx-quill": "^7.1.2",
    "ngx-sortablejs": "^3.1.4",
    "ngx-stripe": "^7.6.0",
    "ngx-toastr": "^11.3.3",
    "ngx-ui-scroll": "^2.0.0",
    "ngx-virtual-scroller": "^3.0.3",
    "ngx-webcam": "^0.2.6",
    "object-path": "^0.11.8",
    "perfect-scrollbar": "^1.4.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.0",
    "quill": "^1.3.6",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.4",
    "socicon": "^3.0.5",
    "sortablejs": "^1.10.2",
    "tooltip.js": "^1.3.3",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "xlsx": "^0.17.3",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "jspdf/file-saver": "1.3.8"
  },

  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.800.6",
    "@angular/cli": "^8.3.22",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "^8.2.14",
    "@interactjs/types": "^1.8.3",
    "@ngrx/schematics": "^8.6.0",
    "@types/chartist": "^0.9.46",
    "@types/highlight.js": "^9.12.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.8",
    "@types/leaflet": "^1.7.4",
    "@types/node": "^12.12.24",
    "@types/object-path": "^0.11.0",
    "@types/sortablejs": "^1.10.6",
    "codelyzer": "^5.2.1",
    "css-loader": "^3.4.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^4.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.2",
    "ts-node": "~8.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.17.0",
    "typescript": "^3.5.3",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.6.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10",
    "webpack-messages": "^2.0.4",
    "webpack-rtl-plugin": "^2.0.0"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

delete the package-lock.json and node_modules. then, rerun the npm install command.

if it still doesn't work install the package

```
npm i 'file-saver@github:eligrey/FileSaver.js#1.3.8'
```